# CSV file to ogive in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, graph

I'm a total newbie with Python, and I'm trying to create an ogive graph (with years and cumulative frequency as the axises) from a CSV file (just two row of values).

Any idea how I can do this without writing the values as I did here?

[image: code snapshot]

I mean lines 44-47, import those values ​​without reading them from the CSV file like I did.

[CSV file](https://mega.nz/folder/5JgSFTYb#WLpnGjlBbfN4DDibaZ01Bg) if you need it.

Comment: You should post your code as text, not an image. It allows us to copy/paste it without requiring us to have to type it all in. You can use [edit] to make improvements to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) functions, these can help with reading your data in. The [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function can be used to group lists together, here it is used to read rows with the same year together.

For example:

```
import operator
from itertools import groupby, accumulate
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

sizeh = 15
plt.xlabel("Years", fontsize=sizeh)
plt.ylabel("Freq", fontsize=sizeh)
plt.title("Promedia erupciones volcanicas", fontsize=sizeh)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]

data = []

with open('volcano_data_2010.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for k, rows in groupby(csv_input, lambda x: x[0] if x else x):
        if k:   # skip empty rows
            data.append([float(k), float(k) + 0.5, len(list(rows))])

data.insert(0, [data[0][0] - 1.0, data[0][1] - 1.0, 0])     # add initial row based on first row
data = list(zip(*data)) #transpose list of rows to list of columns
frecAq = list(accumulate(data[2], operator.add))

plt.plot(data[0], frecAq, "o-", color="blue", label="Ojiva")
plt.bar(data[1], frecAq, width=1, color="cyan", edgecolor="black")
plt.show()
```

Giving you output as:

[image: matplotlib graph output]